# VSCode launch.json's attribute 'skipFiles' not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Vscode debugger didn't skip *node_internals*. I don't know what i'm missing here. Below is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
      
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Build and run Project",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/out/code/main.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "env": {"NODE_PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/out"},
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
                "/<node_internals>/**",
                "**/<node_internals>/**",
                "<node_internals>/internal/**",

            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ]
        }


        
    ]
}
```

I tried all the possible glob patterns but debugger didn't skip the specified paths.

node and npm version

> v14.16.0 and 6.14.11

code version(linux)

> 1.55.0
> c185983a683d14c396952dd432459097bc7f757f
> x64

Any help is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Windows or Linux? I've found that the skip files syntax is dependent on the platform and the / (Linux) or \ (Windows) that each requires. Also I don't believe you need the root locations for the folders e.g. `/<node_internals>/`

I've had success by providing both forms as I move between Windows and Linux frequently:

```
"skipFiles": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
  "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\**\\*.js",
  "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
  "<node_internals>\\**\\*.js",
]
```

I do hope there's a simpler answer out there but I have yet to find it.

Comment: It's linux(Ubuntu 20.04) actually.

Comment: Yeah this is just not true.

Comment: Confirmed this is still true as of October 2023, at least for the node_modules paths.  The node_internals paths are always forward-slash since they don't represent actual files.  Also, for reasons unknown to me, sometimes VSCode breaks inside (rst)/node_modules.  So in summary you need this to completely avoid breaking on files that are not "Just My Code":

`"skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "**/node_modules/**", "**\\node_modules\\**"]`